# Best behavior on error during multipart stream

Tags: go, http, multipart

I have implemented a CSV export endpoint that is grabbing data from a database, row by row, and writing each line to `BodyWriter`. This *must* happen line by line, because the implementation needs to be conscious of memory consumption...

Here is a naive pseudo implementation:

```
rows, err := db.Query(q)
if err != nil {
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError) // <-- location 0
  return
}

for rows.Next() {
  if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    // <-- location 1
    return
  }

  r := result{}
  if err := rows.Scan(&r); err != nil {
    // <-- location 2
    return
  }

  stringSlice := convertToStringSlice(r)
  err := w.Write([]byte(line))
  if err != nil {
    // <-- location 3
    return
  }
}

return  // <-- location 4
```

**In location 0** - there is only one call to `BodyWriter.WriteHeader` so no problem.

**In location 4** - I've already implicitly called `BodyWriter.WriteHeader` by calling `BodyWriter.Write`. Once I return, the `BodyWriter` is probably released and that is how (I assume) how the connection is closed (client gets EOF?).

---

But what if an error occurs after I've already written a few lines, in position 1/2/3? How do I differentiate this from the situation when we return in location 4?

I want to somehow notify the client that something went wrong, but the 200 status was already sent...

It also seems that Golang standard `http` library manages the connection internally and does not expose an easy way to manually close the TCP connection.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: There's no need to handle 3 because the client disconnected.  There are a few options for 1 and 2: (A) Buffer the entire response and only write when query is successful.  (B) Write data understood by the client to indicate an error.  (C) Hijack and close the connection.

Comment: Of these three options, (A) is not viable because we must be memory conscious (the stream might be very large). (B) requires custom behavior on the client side, since we can only start writing part of the response after setting a 200 status and we needs to handle an error that takes place afterwards. I will try to implement (C) as it seems the most viable 'server side' solution.

Answer (score 0):

use the context package
so if the frontend close the request you are not endup reading data and processing data from your database for no use

```golang
func test3Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rows, err := db.QueryContext(r.Context(), q)
}
```

the `*http.Request` have a context that is active while the request is active so if it gets an error that 'the context is closed' which means that the frontend dropped the request in the middle of the request

---

you can't update the `w.WriteHeader(200)` or call `w.WriteHeader(200)` after writing to the body it needs to be called before writing to the body, 
you will need to send the error in that row, also even it didn'

```golang
for rows.Next() {

    res := result{}
    if err := rows.Scan(&res); err != nil {
        // <-- location 2
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "cant read row from the db error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    stringSlice, err := convertToStringSlice(r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "cant process row %+v, error %v\n", res, stringSlice)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintln(w, stringSlice)
}
```

---

if you do want to return a 500 on a scan error, scan all rows to memory and if there is an error return an 500 else return all rows

```golang
func csvHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    rows, err := db.QueryContext(r.Context(), q)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    var list []*result
    for rows.Next() {
        
        res := &result{}
        if err := rows.Scan(res); err != nil {
            // <-- location 2
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError) 
            return
        }
        list = append(list, res)

    }

    csvEnc := csv.NewWriter(w)
    for _, res := range list {
        err =   csvEnc.Write(convertToStringSlice(res)...) 
    }
    
    if err != nil {
        // <-- location 3
        // handle response writing error
        return
    }
    return

}
```

this solution is using more memory than the previous example

Comment: This tackles the situation when the client closes the connection. What about when the server needs to terminate after writing part of the response (for example Kubernetes pods scaling down), or when the server encountered an error (for example, database becoming unavailable) after writing part of the response?

Comment: in most cases of HTTP  response like JSON data, you have the whole response ready before it writes anything to the client so you can determine if there is an error, but here you are trying to stream data directly from the database there is no way to update your status code too 500 after writing to the body if you can save everything to memory you can check if there is an error and return a 500

Comment: i added to the answer an example